# How to measure mongodb index time?

Tags: mongodb

we can use

> db.phones.find({field: 'value'}).explain()

to get the 'millis' of query.

but what if i want to know the time(cost) to make index

something like

> db.phones.ensureIndex({area:1}).explain()

can i use mongoshell or another better ways to measure the time of making index?

Comment: I am really unsure why you would want to known this unless you planned to make indexes dynamically which would be a really bad idea, however, you could use currentOP() to see if the indexer is still running.

Comment: it's just for my curiosity :)

Comment: I don't think it will go to the profile collection, I think only physical queries will as such I think the only way atm is through profiling currentOP

Comment: I should clear one thing up as well, the millis in explain is not of the query but of the explain, if you want the millis of the query you gotta look in the `system.profile` collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cost of building an index is affected by many variables including the complexity of the index, the amount of documents to index, and what else your MongoDB server is doing at the time.

There isn't an `explain()` equivalent to estimate the cost, however you can definitely get a sense of the elapsed time to build the initial index:

- The `mongo` shell has a `verbose` mode which will show you how long operations take.  Enable this option and then build the index in the foreground:

  ```
  > set verbose true
  > db.tweets.ensureIndex({'lang':1,'protected':1})
  Inserted 1 record(s) in 262ms
  ```
- Grep your `mongod` log for "build index" to see indexes being built (either foreground or background) and the associated timing:

  ```
  > grep "build index" /path/to/mongodb.log

  Wed Jan  1 12:45:05.102 [conn3] build index twitter.tweets { lang: 1.0, protected: 1.0 }
  Wed Jan  1 12:45:05.363 [conn3] build index done.  scanned 51428 total records. 0.26 secs
  ```

Comment: Pro tip: If you like the "verbose" shell mode you can enable it by default by adding `_verboseShell=true;` to your [`~/.mongorc.js` file](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongo-mongorc-file).